# How to validate year range in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this regex to validate years:

```
/^(201[5-9]|202[0-5])/.test(year) ? true : false
```

As you can see years it has such pattern: `current_year + 10.years`, how to do it without hardcoding this way? I need something like this, but it's in Ruby: `valid_years = (Time.now.year..(Time.now.year+10))`

Comment: Compare the year as a number to the years (numbers) of interest. Or strings; with years close to the present time string comparison will work too.

Comment: can you give some example, didn't get you what you said

Comment: Create the string dynamically, you can then create a regex object using the string. Try it, should be pretty easy

Answer (score 0):

You can build the regex string and then use that to create the regex object, it pretty simple to do. Here is an example, though it's a *rushed hack-together* so you can probably refactor to make it more simple and readable, but it does work as it is:

```
var start = 2015;
var text = '' + start;
var x = parseInt(start / 10, 10);
var y = start % 10;
var regexString = '^(' + text.substring(0, 3) + '[' + y + '-9]|' + text.substring(0, 2) + (parseInt(text[2]) + 1) + '[0';
if(y > 0)
    regexString += '-' + y;
regexString += '])';
console.log(regexString);

var regex = new RegExp(regexString);
var year = '2020';
var result = regex.test(year) ? true : false;
console.log(result);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6sw04xt1/)